# Malformed collection indexer Error on IIS Configuration Script

Tags: iis

I'm trying to allow HTTP verbs via CMD commands and to do that I run this command which I got from Microsoft's [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis):

```
appcmd.exe set config "websiteName" /section:requestfiltering /+verbs.[verb='OPTIONS',allowed='true']
```

The full error message I get is:

```
ERROR ( message:Malformed collection indexer; format is [@position,name='value',name2='value2',...].
The @position specifier is optional, and be '@start', '@end', or '@N' where N is a numeric index into the collection. )
```

What's wrong with my command?

Comment: You can try this command: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/handlers/#appcmdexe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/handlers/#appcmdexe).

Comment: Oh, I needed double quotes after `/+` and `]` then. Thank you, you can post it as an answer if you want and I could accept it.